# Inheritance and extension method

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

Consider this simple code:

```
public void Main()
{
    var d = new Derived();

    test(d);
}

public void test(Base parameter)
{
    parameter.Validate();
}

public class Base
{
}
public class Derived : Base
{
}

public static class Validation
{
    public static void Validate(this Base b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validation for base");
    }
    public static void Validate(this Derived d)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validation for Derived");
    }
}
```

When the test method is called, it will execute the Validate method which takes the base parameter, as opposed as if I had called `d.Validate()` .

How can I force the test method to call the proper Validate method, without making a type test in it?

Comment: You can't through the use of extension methods. Extension methods are resolved at compile time, while you want to make checks at runtime.

Comment: Extension methods are not polymorphic. Since `parameter` is a `Base`, the method that extends `Base` will be called even if the passed object is actually a `Derived`. You could fix that by providing an overload of `test()` that takes a `Derived`, but this solution does not scale well if you have numerous derived classes.

Comment: `((Derived)parameter).Validate();`, but you should be looking at another way to skin the cat. This makes maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: @xanatos ok, but even with regular static methods I get the same result. Seems that I wil need to chose another way to go

Comment: @BradChristie good point, this nightmare is exactly one of the things that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @SomebodyPleaseHelpme Because only `virtual` method are built to differentiate at runtime. But you must declare them "inside" the `Base`-`Derived` classes.

Comment: @SomebodyPleaseHelpme You can read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16106/Dynamic-Dispatching) (read even the "Another simpler solution..." comment)... It is about dynamic dispatching. The visitor pattern is showed, as is a Dictionary based dispatcher.

Answer (score 3):

You're wanting a *virtual* extension method which is not supported.  Extension methods are just syntactic sugar around static method calls which are bound at compile-time.  You'd have to add some dynamic dispatching by looking at the run-time type to see which extension method should be called.

In your case, why not just make `Validate` a virtual method of the base class?

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Validate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validation for base");
    }
}
public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void Validate()
    {
        base.Validate();  // optional
        Console.WriteLine("Validation for Derived");
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the questioner used extension methods in the first place, chances are they do not have access to the implementations of `Base` and `Derived`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it's possible, but the code provided doesn't indicate that.